# Tomcat hot deployment with maven war plugin

Tags: tomcat, deployment

Can you please provide step by step to hot deploy tomcat with my war file.

Answer (score 0):

Reference [this](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/08/10/configuring-eclipse-tomcat-spring) to know how to configure tomcat in eclipse

Once tomcat is configured deploy the exploded war (not noraml war)file on tomcat. exploded war is useful for hot deploy.